# Inserting Objects from an Array into sql

Tags: java, mysql

**my Code**

```
public void commitContractor()
     {
         for (Contractor c: Contractor.contractorArray)
         {
             String dbHolder = "";
             dbHolder = "INSERT INTO SYSTEM.CONTRACTOR(CONTRACTORID, FIRSTTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLEINITIAL, HOUSENUMBER, STREET, CITYCOUNTY, STATEABB, COUNTRYABB, ZIPCODE, FEE, LASTUPDATEDBY, LASTUPDATED) VALUES(";
             dbHolder += c.getContractorID() + ", ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getFirstName() + "', ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getLastName() + ", ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getMiddleInitial() + "', ";
             dbHolder += c.getHouseNumber() + ", ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getStreet() + "', ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getCityCounty() + ", ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getStateAbb() + "', ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getCountryAbb() + ", ";
             dbHolder += c.getZipcode() + "', ";
             dbHolder += c.getFee() + ", ";
             dbHolder += "'" + c.getLastUpdatedBy() + "', to_date(";
             dbHolder += c.getLastUpdated() + "','yyyy-MM-dd'),')";

             System.out.println(dbHolder);

                sendDBCommand(dbHolder); // sends sql line to db
//                dbHolder = ""; 
         }
     }
```

**ends here**

```
INSERT INTO SYSTEM.CONTRACTOR(CONTRACTORID, FIRSTTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLEINITIAL, HOUSENUMBER, STREET, CITYCOUNTY, STATEABB, COUNTRYABB, ZIPCODE, FEE, LASTUPDATEDBY, LASTUPDATED) VALUES(1000, 'gdgsd', 'gdsg, 'g', 345, 'gfsdg', 'gdgf, 'CA', 'IRL, 3453', 535.0, 'Taylor Bailey', to_date(2017-02-01','yyyy-MM-dd'),')

INSERT INTO SYSTEM.CONTRACTOR(CONTRACTORID, FIRSTTNAME, LASTNAME, MIDDLEINITIAL, HOUSENUMBER, STREET, CITYCOUNTY, STATEABB, COUNTRYABB, ZIPCODE, FEE, LASTUPDATEDBY, LASTUPDATED) VALUES(1000, 'gdgsd', 'gdsg, 'g', 345, 'gfsdg', 'gdgf, 'CA', 'IRL, 3453', 535.0, 'Taylor Bailey', to_date(2017-02-01','yyyy-MM-dd'),')
```

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma
>
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Lab1.CIS484Lab1.commitContractor(CIS484Lab1.java:316)
>       at Lab1.CIS484Lab1.lambda$start$2(CIS484Lab1.java:244)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>       at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>       at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
>       at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>       at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>       at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>       at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>       at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>       at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Your code is at high risk for SQL injection attacks. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: I have just updated the single-quotations in the code; could please accept the update; if the error remains their, please let us know.